# Bluetooth on wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, bluetooth, connect

I need to develop an app, which has to connect to a bluetooth module, how can I do this?

Comment: I dont know if you still need to information but for WP8 a Nokia Engineer (Justin Angel) has release a Bluetooth SDK   [link] (http://metroeeg.codeplex.com/documentation)

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to get access to Bluetooth in current versions of WP7 API.

Comment: And there is no any undocument API. Thank you.

Comment: There is actually a way to work with Bluetooth. And this way is only available for OEM and mobile operators.

Comment: how is that possible ? Do we need external library or use our own btstack ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the Launcher “ConnectionSettingsTask” to achieve it.

Just use the ConnectionSettingsType to Bluetooth and call the show method of the ConnectionSettingsTask . This will Launch the Bluetooth Settings Window and lets the user to change the Bluetooth settings or even enable or disable the Bluetooth.

You use the Launcher , use the namespace Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;

```
private void LaunchBluetoothSettingsForm()
    {
       ConnectionSettingsTask connectionSettingsTask = new ConnectionSettingsTask();
       connectionSettingsTask.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.Bluetooth;
       connectionSettingsTask.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've develop a application for send and receive image/video/audio files for Windows Phone, BI submit this application on microsoft store, They rejected ma application. they said that this application allow users to send copyright protected data, so they can't publish this kind of application.

Answer (score 2):

As of today we developers don't have access to the bluetooth module, hopefully in WP8 we will have access to it through the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Use this codes for your button event. You can also enable Wifi and even airplane mode with this codes. Just replace the word Blutooth to Wifi or airplane mode.

```
private void Blutooth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ConnectionSettingsTask Task = new ConnectionSettingsTask();
   Task.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.Bluetooth;
   Task.Show();
}
```